# How to disable macOS xpc service from loading/activated?

Tags: macos, shell, command

We could use launchctl to disable/remove unused agent/daemon in macOS, is there any way to disable/unload xpc service from starting/activating?

e.x. to disable `com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis.animationperfd`

Any advice or comment is welcome ~

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way, just using the plist of the XPC Service as param:

```
 launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.your.xpc_sercice_name.plist
```